# Why must we bind a Java project to a project in Sonar instead of the Quality Profile

Tags: intellij-idea, sonarqube, sonarlint

Very confused on how SonarLint works and keep running into issues between SonarLint in IntelliJ and SonarQube, maybe someone can offer some insight.

First, I don't understand why are we binding the code to a project. From what I understand, all the rules are in a Quality Profile, wouldn't it make more sense to just bind to a quality profile rather than a specific branch of a project? Not sure if it's that our SonarQube was not configured with best practices, but anytime I want to ensure I'm using the correct rules, I have to go through a huge list of projects and branches in IntelliJ to bind to vs just going through only two quality profiles. Any reason why?

In addition, my local IntelliJ plugin raises issues that's not even configured in the SonarQube server. I made sure I'm in connected mode and the binding was updated recently, but I keep getting these ghost rules. Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Binding to a project makes sense, because that's where you assign quality profile **and other settings** such as exclusions, that are **project-specific**. So it is not devoid of sense.

Binding to a Quality Profile could also be useful for some situations; perhaps you have a feature request there ;)

(I realize I'm only addressing the primary question, the one that is featured in the title -- no good answer for the secondary question)